# Import sql file into laravel sail mysql container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I'm using laravel sail and I try to import sql file into mysql container, is it possible to do that?

I tried this command (file.sql is in the same directory where I launched sail command):

`sail exec mysql mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

But I had this error "the input device is not a TTY"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sail mysql << file.sql
```

or

```
cat file.sql | sail mysql
```

If you are using MariaDB just replace mysql with mariadb.
Also in the defailt sail docker-compose.yml port 3306 of the database is exposed.

That means, if you have installed a local mysql client you can connect to localhost but there is a twist:
If you use mysql or mysqldump with -h localhost the tries to use a socket but you can force it to use 3306 if you use -h 127.0.0.1

```
# Does NOT work
$ mysql -hlocalhost -usail -p laravel
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

# WORKS
$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -usail -p laravel
Enter password:
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried `sail mysql < file.sql` and it works, thanks